# Chef: Can I share common per-environment run list items?

Tags: ruby, deployment, chef-infra

I'm using environments in chef, and I want to use per-environment run lists. The problems is that I don't want to repeat myself (like I'm doing now). Example:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "default_attributes": {
  },
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "env_run_lists": {
    "production": [
      # Has less packages because services are spread across specialized nodes
      "role[base]",
      "recipe[mysql::client]",
      "recipe[myapp]"
    ],
    "staging": [
      # Has less packages because services are spread across specialized nodes
      "role[base]",
      "recipe[mysql::client]",
      "recipe[myapp]"
    ],
    "development": [
      "role[base]",
      "recipe[mysql::client]",
      "recipe[myapp]",
      "role[utility]",
      "role[cache]"
    ]
  },
  "run_list": [

  ],
  "description": "The myapp.com core application role",
  "chef_type": "role",
  "override_attributes": {

  }
}
```

Is there a way I can avoid repeating this?

```
      "role[base]",
      "recipe[mysql::client]",
      "recipe[myapp]",
```

I just want to avoid environment run lists falling out of sync and breaking deployments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time, no. Roles are purely declarative and not dynamic in that way. You could create a role that includes those three items and include that in the per environment run lists.

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better guy to to answer my question — thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible in JSON, however it is possible if you use Ruby DSL to define your role.

This is how your role file would look like:

```
name "myapp"
description   "Description of the role"
base_run_list = [ "role[base]", "recipe[mysql::client]", "recipe[myapp]" ]
env_run_lists "production" => base_run_list, "staging" => base_run_list , "development" => base_run_list + ["role[utility]", "role[cache]"]
```

`base_run_list` is your list of common recipes.